# Assign Last Two Lines of Text as Variable via Batch Script

Tags: text, batch-file

Hi I have a text file in which I need to use the last two lines as two variables in a batch script. Example:

file.txt contains:

```
Release2010
Release2011
Release2013
```

I need var1 = Release2011 and var2 = Release2013. The length of the file will vary but I will always need the last two lines.

Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: Thanks both of you. I truly appeciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might try this:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (file) DO (
    SET "var2=!var1!"
    SET "var1=%%a"
)
ECHO(var1: %var1%
ECHO(var2: %var2%
```

---

and the same without `delayed expansion`:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (file) DO (
    CALL SET "var2=%%var1%%"
    SET "var1=%%a"
)
ECHO(var1: %var1%
ECHO(var2: %var2%
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it without enabling delayed expansion.

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F %%A IN (InFile.txt) DO (
   CALL :SetSecondLastLine
   SET LastLine=%%A
   )
ECHO.SecondLastLine=%SecondLastLine%
ECHO.LastLine=%LastLine%
pause
GOTO :eof

:SetSecondLastLine
SET SecondLastLine=%LastLine%
GOTO:EOF
```